# How to check if a dictionary has the same elements wanted from a list?

Tags: python

I am working on creating a service menu where the user gets to choose which service he wants and add it to a list.

After the user has chosen the services he wants, he would then proceed to checkout where the total price of those services is added together and he pays.

I currently have a function that gets and stores the services that the user wants from a dictionary:

```
userInput = ""

servicesAvailableFull = {'Firewall Service' : 1.2, 'Security Ops Centre' : 4.2,
                         'Hot Site' : 8.5}
servicesAvailable = ["Firewall Service", "Security Ops Centre", "Hot Site"]
userAddedServices = []

print("+++ Welcome to Electronic Services and Protection: +++")

while userInput != "Q":
    menu()
    userInput = input("Please input your choice of action ('Q' to exit):  ")

    if userInput == "1":
        displayServices(servicesAvailableFull , servicesAvailable, userAddedServices)
        print(userAddedServices)

    elif userInput == "4":
        payment(userAddedServices, servicesAvailableFull)


def displayServices(availServiceFull, availService, serviceToAdd):
    userInput = ""
    counter = 1
    elementToTransfer = ""
    while userInput != "Q":
        print("\n")
        print("Yes, we have the following service(s): ")
        for x, service in availServiceFull.items():
            print(f" {counter}.  {x}   : ${service}/year")
            counter += 1
        userInput = input(
            "Enter the service(s) that you would like to add, or 'Q' to stop: ")
        try:
            if userInput.isnumeric()==False:
                raise ValueError
            #elif int(userInput) > int(len(userAddedServices)) or int(userInput) <= 0:
            #   raise ValueError
            else:
                 elementToTransfer = availService[int(userInput) - 1]
                 if elementToTransfer in serviceToAdd:
                    print("Sorry, you added that service already.")
                    counter = 1
                    continue
                 else:
                    serviceToAdd.append(elementToTransfer)
                    print(serviceToAdd)
                    counter = 1

        except ValueError:
            counter = 1
            print("Please enter a numeric value")
```

Right now I have a list which contains the services the user wants to add, and a dictionary containing both the services and the price of the services.

I am currently working on the `payment()` function, but I am not sure how to get the program to print out both the services the user wants to add and their corresponding price.

Like this:

1. Firewall Service: $1.2k/year
2. Security Ops    : $4.2k/year

I am able to print from the list containing the user added services, but I am unsure how to access the prices from the dictionary.

Comment: This is a very convoluted question and seems like a very specific home work. Please generic questions that others can benefit as well

Answer (score 1):

to access a dictionary value:

```
x = {"elem": "value"}

print(x["elem"])
```

Output:

```
"value"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary keys match with the list content this should be straightforward:

```py
for s in userAddedServices:
  price = servicesAvailableFull[s]
  print(f"{s} ${price}k/year")
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary has 2 parts.

1. Key
2. Value

It is like {'key': 'value}

You can loop over it like

```
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(servicesAvailableFull.items()):
    print(i+1, key, ':', value,'$/year')
```

This will give you your desired output as

1 Firewall Service : 1.2 $/year

2 Security Ops Centre : 4.2 $/year

3 Hot Site : 8.5 $/year

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way as i get your question is to make 'for' loop through items in the list user services. Accessing dictionary values with [dict[key]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-accessing-key-value-in-dictionary/) method:

```
for item in userAddedServices:
    print(f"{userAddedServices.index(item) + 1}. {item} : ${servicesAvailableFull[item]}k/year.")
```

For userAddedServices == servicesAvailable this returns:

1. Firewall Service : $1.2k/year.
2. Security Ops Centre : $4.2k/year.
3. Hot Site : $8.5k/year.